# Prevent UIView shadow under view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, shadow

I'm looking to make a custom `UIView` subclass that has a "hole" in it through which the view below it is visible.  I've already accomplished this using some Core Graphics drawing and clipping.  Fun stuff.

I'd also like this view, which is called `WheelDetailView`, to have a drop shadow.  Easy enough.  I've accomplished that with something like:

```
[[self layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[[self layer] setShadowRadius:4.0];
[[self layer] setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[[self layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 2)];
```

The problem is, this setup gives me a shadow inside the "hole" that I've created in my view.  While I realize that this makes perfect sense, since you would expect to see a shadow there in real life, I'd prefer to only have the drop shadow appear around my view.

Here's how it appears now:

[image: Hole with auto-shadow]

<sub>I intentionally blurred part of the wheel for anonymity; you can ignore that.</sub>

As you can see, the shadow is present both outside the view and within it.  Does anyone know of a good way to remove this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it make sense to put the WheelView above the view?

Or you can remove the view's shadow and use a separate view with shadow, then place it behind all the views

Or an image of shadow and place it behind all views

Comment: I like what you're thinking, but unfortunately, I can't do that.  The wheel itself is a `UIImageView` which could theoretically be placed above my `WheelDetailView`, but that would cause some issues.  The blue beam that extends toward the bottom of the frame, for example, must remain above the wheel, but below the `WheelDetailView`.  Additionally, the `WheelDetailView` animates in from offscreen, and it wouldn't look right if it animated "under" the wheel.

Comment: So I would use an image for the shadow and place it behind all views. Or even create an image for the entire WheelDetailsView that includes the hole and the shadow as u like. Try doing it with photoshop or any other graphic tool, it not supposed to be difficult and from my experience  it will be much better (in terms of performance) then drawing all with core graphics.

Comment: Your solution *does* work, so I'll give you the check.  I was hoping, though, for someone to come up with a CG solution.  Maybe they still will.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Old topic but for the record there is no way I am aware of to prevent a shadow to go under the view which is projecting it